# How to Update Typescript React Redux State With One or More Reducer State Values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

With the below Typescript React Redux set up, when dispatching, is it common/best practice to always update whole object

```
dispatch(saveSettings({...state, ...color: 'blue' }))
```

or individual values from the SettingsInterface

```
dispatch(saveSettings({color: 'blue' }))
```

For updating indivial values how should the action creator argument accept one or more keys of the SettingsInterface

```
const saveSettings = (settings: SettingsInterface) =>... // action creator argument is currently expecting all from the SettingsInterface
```

setup

```
const SAVE_SETTINGS = "SAVE_SETTINGS"

export interface SettingsInterface {
   color: `red` | `blue`
   preference: string
   location: string
}

interface SaveSettingsInterface {
    type: typeof SAVE_SETTINGS
    settings: SettingsInterface
}

export type settingsActionTypes = SaveSettingsInterface

// action creator
export const saveSettings = (settings: SettingsInterface): settingsActionTypes => {
    return {
        type: SAVE_SETTINGS,
        settings
    }
}


//reducer
const settings = (state = settingsInitialState, action: settingsActionTypes): SettingsInterface => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SAVE_SETTINGS_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, ...action.settings }
        default:
            return state
       }
    }
```

and lastly, in the onChange handler where I am updating the 'color' state; how to ensure the value is one of the colors of the string literal union('red' | 'blue') specified in the SettingsInterface?

```
 // radio buttons onChangeHandler
 const handleOnChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        let newColor = event.target.value
    
        dispatch(saveSettings({ color: newColor }))
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m on my phone so forgive my bad formatting.

For your first question: you should pass the minimal amount of information in an action.  So just the changed properties.  It is the job of the reducer to merge the changes with the existing state.  So use this one:

```
dispatch(saveSettings({color: 'blue' }))
```

To pass an incomplete object, use the typescript utility type Partial.

```
const saveSettings = (settings: Partial<SettingsInterface>)
```

You can get the union of acceptable color values by using

```
type Color = SettingsInterface[‘color’]
```

But event.target.value will always be just a string, so you have to use “as” to assert that it is the more specific type Color.

```
dispatch(saveSettings({ color: newColor as Color }))
```

Comment: [const saveSettings = (settings: Partial<SettingsInterface>)] would mean the action that is returned by the action creator is incompatible because the settings type -SettingsInterface now includes an undefined.

please view on codesandbox --- 

https://codesandbox.io/s/36w5n